# Show custom physicsMsg

Tags: gazebo-gui

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have implemented my own physics engine into Gazebo through System plugin.
The next that I want to do is to publish my own physicsMsg and show them on property pane.
It's easy for me to understand how to create the custom message and publish it.
But I have no idea how to show it on the property pane.
Is it possible to show it. in that case, how to do?

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13739/show-custom-physicsmsg/) by [aaggjajptj](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2682/aaggjajptj/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-06-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Wow, you've integrated your physics engine with Gazebo using a system plugin, that's amazing!

Not sure exactly how your implementation works, but here's how it works for the default physics engines:

1. `gui::ModelListWidget` publishes a request for `physics_info` [here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/4004fbd7deede758c0ca0fbc7c906e62b0a808a4/gazebo/gui/ModelListWidget.cc?fileviewer=file-view-default#ModelListWidget.cc-198).
2. When the running physics engine is ODE for example, `physics::ODEPhysics` fills a message with physics info [here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/4004fbd7deede758c0ca0fbc7c906e62b0a808a4/gazebo/physics/ode/ODEPhysics.cc?fileviewer=file-view-default#ODEPhysics.cc-238)
3. `gui::ModelListWidget` checks the response corresponds to the request it sent [here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/4004fbd7deede758c0ca0fbc7c906e62b0a808a4/gazebo/gui/ModelListWidget.cc?fileviewer=file-view-default#ModelListWidget.cc-458) and fills the panel [here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/4004fbd7deede758c0ca0fbc7c906e62b0a808a4/gazebo/gui/ModelListWidget.cc?fileviewer=file-view-default#ModelListWidget.cc-2881).

So I think you'd somehow need to subscribe to `~/request` for `physics_info` and publish your message to `~/response`. But I think you'll need to make sure the default physics engine doesn't respond first.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aaggjajptj](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2682/aaggjajptj/) on 2016-06-30**:
Thank you for your message.

I could figure out how physics info on GUI is being updated from a physics engine.
Another thing is that I am wondering if I could implement my own msg::Physics message passing between gui and an engine , such as what you explained in the first answer, through plugin system.
Because I would like to deploy only the plugin to my team members

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2016-06-30**:
Have you tried subscribing to `~/request` from your plugin and sending your own physics message in the response?

**Comment by [aaggjajptj](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2682/aaggjajptj/) on 2016-07-04**:
Yes, I tried. I could see some parameters in msgs::Physics updating on the model list pane regarding to every response from my physics engine.
In this case, I just inserted code subscribing ~/response in my physics.
The next I want to do is to send another msgs::Physics which I newly defines, such as msgs::Physics2, to gui.
Is it acceptable for the model list pane to show the new msg without code modification in ModelListWidget class?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2016-07-05**:
Oh I see, adding your own custom fields to the ModelListWidget will be difficult, or maybe even impossible, without changing the Gazebo source code.

**Comment by [aaggjajptj](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2682/aaggjajptj/) on 2016-07-07**:
Your comment is the same as my understanding. I don't get in depth of the gui any more. Thanks!